calculating percentage normalisation
Please don't laugh or close this post I am confused as to how I can calculate the percentage normalization occurring post treatment.
So, here is a background of the problem, I have reading from controls and diseased samples that were treated with drugs A and B. The readings are at two time points for the drugs, at time 0 and at time x. These are recorded in the table below.
    Gene    Control DrugA.to    DrugA.tx    DrugB.to    DrugB.tx
GeneA1  0.255137598 0.996823656 0.841427508 0.838585838 0.637163007
GeneA2  0   1.002128241 1.088924271 0.708817547 0.858001516
GeneA3  0.649779583 0.970614468 0.883699106 0.863034514 0.863533489
GeneA4  0.261785973 1.228567772 0.860292411 0.950751742 1.026950264
GeneA5  0   0.964363461 1.177734151 0.831123556 1.496702315
GeneA6  0.539853517 1.185978246 0.999361733 0.88790566  0.926980252
GeneA7  0.609842771 1.245618868 1.095380831 0.91075683  1.038654277
GeneA8  0.546278983 1.143557146 1.31081493  0.961478462 0.955452931
GeneA9  0.278067545 1.565468159 1.2463365   1.039837814 0.961697678
GeneA10 0.841483131 1.637659304 1.195102944 1.171462249 1.274326013
GeneA11 1.066410285 1.40104267  1.200123252 0.957711736 1.525794178
GeneA12 2.613408631 1.052950881 0.908745691 0.863034514 0.892767429
GeneA13 2.583216456 1.105396939 1.242388547 0.87318548  0.623271818
GeneA14 2.800415579 1.097795107 0.999763993 0.893300428 0.863533489
GeneA15 1.044277784 1.534601183 1.213267026 1.08889909  1.797417187
GeneA16 0   2.476333854 2.055473655 1.021699805 1.138185985
GeneA17 1.861254616 1.147626264 1.72825638  1.009700622 0.963547498
GeneA18 0.850735068 2.07213776  1.675176397 1.352168483 1.026950264
GeneA19 2.784079193 1.097795107 1.03334891  0.863034514 1.246543636
GeneA20 0.600378056 1.55167128  1.837088792 1.116134855 2.35125585
GeneA21 0.789140187 2.195590214 2.109625834 1.322807345 1.200786951
GeneA22 0.560671399 1.559604269 2.014979635 1.634260415 1.910905861
GeneA23 3.176300908 1.200678944 1.406041611 0.890985128 1.200293773
GeneA24 1.959958568 1.747658569 1.31081493  1.394319133 1.533792282
GeneA25 1.815692    1.933923319 1.221955458 1.08889909  1.971098865
GeneA26 2.918198494 1.2461771   1.847890057 0.998327027 1.200786951

Now ho can I show and/or calculate that drug A or drug b brings more normalization towards controls. What I mean by normalization towards control is that, after treatment the gene expression at time x was either reduced or increased but it went in the direction of control example GeneA1 has expression of 0.25 at control and in diseased samples that were treated with drug A the expression  was reduced by 15.15% ((0.84-0.99)/0.99) while treatment with drug B expression was reduced by 24%. Therefor for gene A it could be said that drug B brings more normalization of expression towards control. Now, instead of single gene I want to compute overall effect of the drug A and B.
I can calculate the fold change or percentage fold change for each gene per drug but how do I show that which drug normalizes gene expression more towards control.
What I have a figure like this in mind where green and violet are drugs A and B.

Thank you for your time and help

Could you tell us more specifically what "normalization towards controls" is and how you would recognize and measure it?

@whuber Please check the edited question. I have elaborated the part of normalization towards control.
